# LWC JS function isn't properly connecting with the Apex Controller

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-wire-adapter

[image]

Steps

1. Type "Some text" in the text field
2. Click Save button
3. Refresh the browser window

Expected Result:
Text field should show "Some text" still, because I have an Apex method updating the object field when user clicks Save.

Actual Result:
Text field is null, and the corresponding field in the backend is null.

Here's the Apex Logs
[image]

Why does it appear to run updateEACheckboxTrackerAndMandatedNotes apex method, but it never prints any of the debug statements?

When I run same Apex method from Anonymous Window, the debug statements print just fine.

---

```
@AuraEnabled
  public static void updateEACheckboxTrackerAndMandatedNotes(
    String siteSurveyId, String[] activityIdsForTracker, String mandatedActivityNotes) {
    System.debug('*** mandatedActivityNotes: ' + mandatedActivityNotes);
    Site_Survey__c siteSurvey = [SELECT Id, Event_Activity_Checkbox_Tracker__c, 
                                        Event_Activities_Checklist_Notes__c
                                 FROM Site_Survey__c 
                                 WHERE Id = :siteSurveyId];
    System.debug('*** siteSurvey: ' + siteSurvey);

    siteSurvey.Event_Activity_Checkbox_Tracker__c = 
      String.join(activityIdsForTracker, ',');
    siteSurvey.Event_Activities_Checklist_Notes__c = mandatedActivityNotes;
    update siteSurvey;
  }
```

---

```
import {LightningElement, wire, track} from 'lwc';
import {CurrentPageReference} from 'lightning/navigation';
import {ShowToastEvent} 
  from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import updateEACheckboxTrackerAndMandatedNotes
  from '@salesforce/apex/EventActivities_Ctrl.updateEACheckboxTrackerAndMandatedNotes';

export default class EventActivitiesChecklist extends LightningElement {

   <other functions removed to focus the conversation>
 
  saveChecklistState() {

    const SUCCESSEVENT = new ShowToastEvent({
      title: 'Saved',
      message: 'Your checklist has been saved.',
      variant: 'success',
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(SUCCESSEVENT);

    this.activityIdsForTracker = [...this.template
                                  .querySelectorAll('lightning-input')]
                                  .filter(element => element.checked)
                                  .map(element => element.dataset.id);
        
    this.mandatedActivityNotes = [this.template.querySelector("lightning-textarea").value];
    console.log('this.mandatedActivityNotes: ',this.mandatedActivityNotes);

    updateEACheckboxTrackerAndMandatedNotes(
      {siteSurveyId:this.siteSurveyId, 
       activityIdsForTracker:this.activityIdsForTracker,
       mandatedActivityNotes: this.mandatedActivityNotes,
      });
  }
```

---

```
<template>
  <lightning-card>

    <div class="slds-form-element slds-m-left_medium slds-m-right_medium">
      <!--label class="slds-form-element__label slds-text-heading_small" for="textarea-id-01">Mandated Activity Notes</label>
      <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <textarea id="textarea-id-01" placeholder="Provide your reasoning here…" class="slds-textarea">
          {mandatedActivityNotes}
        </textarea>
      </div-->
      <lightning-textarea 
        name="mandatedNotes" 
        label="Mandated Activity Notes" 
        value={mandatedActivityNotes}
      ></lightning-textarea>
    </div>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: Does your profile have access to the apex class?

Comment: this.mandatedActivityNotes is an array, try taking off the brackets [] in the assignment.

Comment: Great question, Kris. I've ran into this in the past. I double checked, and indeed my profile does appear on the Class's Security screen.

Comment: That did @CyberJus! Thanks! Feel free to create your solution as an answer, so I can mark it such

Comment: Any tips on debugging for next time would be a bonus.

Comment: you should try catching the error from the promise chain of your apex method, also https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/08/error-handling-best-practices-for-lightning-web-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your this.mandatedActivityNotes variable with [] which defines it as an array. Your apex method signature is expecting a String.

```
this.mandatedActivityNotes = this.template.querySelector("lightning-textarea").value;
```